# how to uninstall a powershell module when it can't find it by name even if it lists the searched name as an installed module?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to uninstall a module from powershell but I can't.

Powershell says it can't find that module by name but when I list all installed modules, it is right there. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or console output. Instead post the text of it and format it as code. Thanks in advacne. When you call `Get-Module` and pipe it to `Select-Obejct -Property *` or `Format-List *` you will see all properties of the module including the path where it's installed. Just delete the folder. ;-)

Comment: I believe that the `Uninstall-Module` command will only work if the module was installed originally using `Install-Module`

Answer (score 0):

Try `Remove-Module -Name oh-my-posh`

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. =>

+ Remove-Module -Name oh-my-posh
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [Remove-Module], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_NoModulesRemoved,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveModuleCommand

Comment: @JoãoMelo Try checking under **C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules** to see if the module is listed there. If not try **C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules** and if still nothing, then **C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules**

Comment: I finally found the module in c:\users\j\onedrive\documents\windowspowershell\modules\oh-my-posh